# how to modify a class when using variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Im finally teaching my self how to use classes and I hit a bump. I want to be able to change how the class behaves depending on what number is given. I pretty sure I overlooking something but I don't know what.

```
class mob(plnul):
        def __init__(self):
                if plnul == 1:
                        self.x, self.y = 16, SCR_HEI/2    #Player
                if plnul == 2:
                        self.x, self.y = SCR_WID-16, SCR_HEI/2   #Enemy
                self.speed = 3
                self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
                self.score = 0
                self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)                           
        def scoring(self):
                scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))          
                if plnul == 1:
                        screen.blit(scoreBlit, (32, 16))    #Player
                if plnul == 2:
                        screen.blit(scoreBlit, (SCR_HEI+92, 16))    #Enemy
                if self.score == 10:
                    if plnul == 1:
                            print ("player 1 wins!")
                    if plnul == 2:
                            print ("player 2 wins!")
                exit()    
 player = mob(1)   #Spawns 1 instance of mob as player 1 names it player
```

Comment: For a Python `class`, the parameter list in parentheses are base classes, not like these passed to function and methods. See [Class Definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class) in the documentation.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? This is a legitimate question with the asker having put some effort into it (as evidenced by the fact they shared their code). The only good reason for closing this might be if it's a duplicate, but AFAIK, there isn't duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.

```
class mob(object):
    def __init__(self, plnul):
         ...
```